# ACF post category – Posts are not saving first time published

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, advanced-custom-fields

there. I’m developing a wordpress site and i’m facing an issue with Advanced Custom Field that I can’t figure out.

I have a category called “nature” and I have create a field using the ACF plugin and set the following rule: POST CATEGORY IS EQUAL TO NATURE.

So, everytime I create a new post and then, inside the post, select the category “nature” at the right bar, it shows the custom fields right away (like ajax or something). The fields just shows. I thought that everything was fine, but there is one important problema with that.

I fill the fields with information, upload images and so on and then I publish. But it doesn’t save the first time I leave the post. It just works fine if I edit the post again and retype and resend all the images and then update the post.

I’ve tried everything, but It just does not work. Can someone help me with that?

Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE - it's not the ideal scenario, but it works fine with CLASSIC EDITOR. I think the issue is related to gutenberg since I've seen some people facing the same problem as me.**

Comment: Can you elaborate on "I've tried everything" - since you're not posting any of  the code that you've tried, it would appear to everyone here that you didn't try anything.  You can edit your question to include your code and desired output.  Include as much detail as possible so that someone can assist you.

Comment: I've tried everything that I thought could make it work: reinstalled the plugin, the theme, the group of fields. Since it's an issue at admin, what else can I do? I don't know what to do. I don't know if it is related to the fact that the fields only shows when I select the category and for some reason it doesn't allow it to save at the first time... I have no idea.

Comment: I forgot to say that It's not a custom post type. It is an ordinary post. The loops shows only the post title, but none of the custom fields are being showed after the first time I publish. Only if I fill everything again. :(